# Convergence of numerical method

Tags: sequences-and-series, na.numerical-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I would like to prove that the following sequence :

$S^{n+1} =1 - I +\frac{β}{α}\ln(S^{n})$,

where $\alpha,\,\beta,\,I$ are constants and $S^{0} = 1$

converges as long as $\alpha\cdot S<\beta.$

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta,I$ positive? Is there a reason to have separate constants $\beta,\alpha$, as opposed to one constant $\gamma>S$?

Comment: @SamZbarsky yes they are possitive..The reason it that it is not supposed to converge when β>α*S

Comment: @SamZbarsky also I is always les than 1

Comment: What do you mean by "converges as long as $\alpha\cdot S<\beta$"? In particular, what is $S$ there? Also, is $S^n$ the $n$th term of the sequence, or is it the $n$th power of $S$?

Comment: I think you have the sign on the inequality in the original question wrong (as written, I think S should repel the sequence). Also, please edit the question to state the condition clearly, since the equation $S=1-I+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\ln(S)$ can have 0, 1, or 2 solutions. Do you mean "There is some solution $S$ satisfying the inequality" or "There are two solutions, of which exactly one satisfies the inequality", or something else?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yeah you are right it's the nth term of S

Comment: And, again, what do you mean by "converges as long as $\alpha\cdot S<\beta$"? In particular, what is $S$ there?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I mean converges as long as a*S^(n)<b

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383992/prove-seirs-series-is-convergent has been rightfully closed and this one is no better (even if we agree to assume that it is a different user), so I'm voting to close and will flag the next time this question appears anywhere in the same apparently meaningless form.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question doesn't make sense as written and the OP is rather clueless about what he really wants to ask.